# Facebook Real-time updates not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm setting up Facebook Real-time updates for an app so that I can read user's status updates as they happen, but I'm not getting updates. As far as I can tell I've set everything up correctly. Here's my subscription:

```
    {
       "data": [
          {
             "object": "user",
             "callback_url": "*****/facebook-rt-callback.aspx",
             "fields": [
                "checkins",
                "feed"
             ],
             "active": true
          }
       ]
    }
```

When I test my subscription, my callback gets the request and FB shows that it worked correctly.
When user's give access to my app, I request scope=user_status,user_checkins. I also have these permissions defined in my app on FB. My test user is able to login and give permission to my app, but when the test user posts status updates or checkins on his timeline, my callback never gets hit.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?